# Python: filling a List of objects from a .txt file

Tags: python, list, file, text

For starters I've programmed in C++ for the past year and a half, and this is the first time I'm using Python.

The objects have two int attributes, say i_ and j_.

The text file is as follows:

```
1,0
2,0
3,1
4,0
...
```

What I want to do is have the list filled with objects with correct attributes. For example,

```
print(myList[2].i_, myList[2].j_, end = ' ')
```

would return

```
3 1
```

Here's my attempt after reading a little online.

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i_ = i
        self.j_ = j   

with open("myFile.txt") as f:

    myList = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(','))) for line in f]

    for line in f:
        i = 0
        while (i < 28):
            myList.append(myClass(line.split(","), line.split(",")))
            i +=1
```

But it doesn't work obviously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `def` needs indented

Comment: @vash_the_stampede yes, I didn't paste it correctly, it's indented in my code!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `while (i < 28):`. Why 28?

Comment: So sorry @slider, forgot to mention. The list size has to be 29 because our assignment said so. There's 29 objects. I guess I could have used while !eof or something but the point of my question is, I can't get to separate the first number and second number separated by a comma and put them in the corresponding attributes of the objects in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with a CSV file you might want to use the `csv` module. First you would pass the file object to the `csv.reader` function and it will return an iterable of rows from the file. From there you can cast it to a list and slice it to the 29 rows you are required to have. Finally, you can iterate over the rows (e.g. [1,0]) and simply unpack them in the class constructor.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = int(i)
        self.j = int(j)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyClass(i={self.i}, j={self.j})"

with open('test.txt') as f:
    rows = [r.strip().split(',') for r in f.readlines()[:29]]
    my_list = [MyClass(*row) for row in rows]

for obj in my_list:
    print(obj.i, obj.j)

print(len(my_list))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! Unfortunately we cannot touch the database and it's a .txt file so I have to work with that.

Comment: There is no database in use. Do you mean you cannot use the standard library?

Comment: I updated the example to use only built-in functions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but you wrote:

with open('csv1.csv') as f:

What I meant was, I have no .csv file, I have a .txt file that I cannot touch (or turn into a csv file somehow)

sorry again in advance if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: A csv is a txt file. Just change the name of the file to your own file name, it'll still work.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `myList = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(','))) for line in f]`. This will give you a list of lists with those pairs converted to ints. But you really want objects from those numbers. So let's do that directly as we iterate through the lines in the file and do away with the next while loop:

```
my_list = []
with open("myFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        nums = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',') if i]
        if len(nums) >= 2:
            my_list.append(myClass(nums[0], nums[1]))
```

Comment: Hi, that's brilliant! but I get:

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: @PersiaShahdi is there a line in the file that is not of the type `1,0`?

Comment: There are lines like `1,2,18` separated by a blank line. But wouldn't that cause the error to say `expected 2, got 3`?

Comment: @PersiaShahdi ok let's be very defensive then and only consider lines with `>= 2` numbers (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

I not sure you really what to stick with this format

```
print(myList[2].i_, myList[2].j_, end = ' ')
```

My solution is quite manual coded and i am using dictionary to store i and j

```
result = {'i':[],
  'j':[]}
```

and below is my code

```
result = {'i':[],
      'j':[]}

with open('a.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', ',')
print(data)

a = data.split(",")
print (a)

b = [x for x in a if x]
print(b)

for i in range( 0, len(b)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        result['i'].append(b[i])
    else:
        result['j'].append(b[i])


print(result['i'])
print(result['j'])
print(str(result['i'][2])+","+ str(result['j'][2]))
```

The result: 3,1